# PHP ftp_connect() returns false always except with first used ftp server..!

Tags: php, ftp, firewall

The problem is ..
I just used ftp_connect() for the first time on my server

```
<?php
$ftp_connect = ftp_connect('ftp.server.com') or die('<b>FTP Connection Error ...</b>');
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_connect, 'ftp_username','ftp_password') or die('<b>FTP Login Error ...Check Your UserName and Password</b>');
ftp_pasv($ftp_connect,true);    
?>
```

It worked fine and returned true.Every thing works fine with that ftp server (ftp.server.com)

Then next time I used the same server and everything was fine...BUT
when I tried with another server (say: ftp.server2.com) it returned false,i.e host not found ..!! 
I tried with all my friends ftp servers  and nothing could connect except that one(ftp.server.com)
what's actually going on ... why is this happening and how can I solve this ... right now i can't connect any ftp server (except my ftp.server.com) ....
Thanx in advance ...

And The above thing works fine on my pc (IIS,PHP 5.3.8)

***Updated :***
ahhh ....... figured out the problem .... but didn't find a solution.!!!!
the server (here: ftp.server.com) has the same IP which the host server, where the above php is hosted - has.... and soo the ftp_connect() worked on it.... 
reason is both the servers ftp and http host are from same web hosting provider...

Now its clear, (I think) that firewall is the main reason for all the problem .... how to fix that firewall...?? plz help.... Thanx again..

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the next server is valid? Can you connect to it from your FTP client?

Comment: Can you connect ftp.server2.com using other tools?

Comment: yaa ftp.server2.com can connect from ftp client (FileZilla)

Comment: Please verify that your server is capable of resolving the names of the servers: [`gethostbyname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) can help with this.

Comment: Yess it can ... !! i get the ip address as the result..

Comment: ftp_connect returning false doesn't mean host-not-found is the only possible error. There's host unreachable, connection refused, etc... Fix your error messages first.

Comment: ok let that be whatever it is... but plz help me solve the probbb...

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying a port number.  PHP's [ftp_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php) will use `21` as the default port number if you don't specify one.  This script may have worked for the first server because it was running on port 21, but the other servers may be failing because they're running on different ports.  Ask your friend(s) what port they're using, or use something like [nmap](http://nmap.org/) to find it yourself.

Comment: no all of the servers run on port 21 itself and also i checked the port and even timeout [ftp_connect(ftp.server2.com,21,150)]...